# Strange array comparison issue

Tags: powershell

I am writing some content to a file and then testing the content of the file it returns false; however the stings are identical.

The string is a large multi-line string. When It this this same code with a simple string, it works as expected.

Please have a look at the following test. I can't explain why comparing the 2 variables returns false but compare-object finds no difference.

The second code example shows expected behaviour.

```
PS H:\DFSMigration> $test = Invoke-Expression -Command "dfscmd.exe /view \\mydomain.com\rootdfs /batchrestore"

PS H:\DFSMigration> $test | Set-Content .\backup.txt

PS H:\DFSMigration> $test2 = Get-Content .\backup.txt

PS H:\DFSMigration> if ($test -eq (Get-Content .\backup.txt)) {"True"} Else{"false"}
false

PS H:\DFSMigration> if ($test -eq $test2) {"True"} Else{"false"}
false

PS H:\DFSMigration> Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $test -DifferenceObject $test2

PS H:\DFSMigration> $test.count
2256

PS H:\DFSMigration> $test2.count
2256

PS H:\DFSMigration> $test.gettype()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array


PS H:\DFSMigration> $test2.gettype()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array
```

This is the expected behaviour:

```
PS H:\DFSMigration> $test =  "This is a test string with loads of foobar"

PS H:\DFSMigration> $test | Set-Content backuptest.txt

PS H:\DFSMigration> $test2 = Get-Content backuptest.txt

PS H:\DFSMigration> If($test -eq $test2){ "The strings are equal"} Else { "They're not equal"}
The strings are equal
```

Comment: All the documentation I'd read suggested that with an array, the comparison operator -eq will work as a filter returning all the values which match. Which should evaluate to $true. However testing this by creating 2 arrays as with the same content seems to backup the answer. 

Seems I misread the docs and it does not compare the array's contents. It's actually looking for $test2 as an element of $test. This was confusing because the my original test code returned strings and not arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$test` and `$test2` are 2 different arrays, and are therefore not equal. If you were to loop over each element in the arrays, you will see that they contain the same strings.

```
for ($i=0; $i -lt $test.Length; $i++) {
    if ($test[$i] -eq $test2[$i]) { "True" } else { "False" }
}
```

Comment: All the documentation I'd read suggested that with an array, the comparison operator -eq will work as a filter returning all the values which match. Which should evaluate to $true. However testing this by creating 2 arrays as with the same content seems to backup your answer.  
Seems I misread the docs and it does not compare the array's contents. It's actually looking for $test2 as an element of $test. 

This was confusing because the my original test code returned strings and not arrays.

Comment: @RoscoeT What that means is that you can do something like `$a = 'a', 'b', 'c'; ($a) -eq 'b'`. That expression will just return the elements from `$a` that equal the string "b". That's not what you're doing, though. You are comparing 2 arrays (`$a1 -eq $a2`). The enumerator functionality built into PowerShell operators does not compare each element from the first array with each element from the second one.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use `Compare-Object` to determine if the arrays are the same.
By default, it find the differences and indicate the side containing each difference. Therefore, if there's no difference, count will be 0.

Note that using this method, the position of each item in the array is not considered as a difference. If different order should be considered as not equal, then a For loop will be better suited.

```
$Arr1 = @('apple', 'banana', 'orange','tomato')
$Arr2 = @('tomato', 'potato', 'carrot')
$Arr3 = @('apple', 'banana', 'orange', 'tomato')

$Same = (Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $Arr1 -DifferenceObject $Arr2).count -eq 0
if ($Same) { Write-Host '$Arr1 is equal to $Arr2' -ForegroundColor Cyan } else { Write-Host ':(- $Arr1 is NOT equal to $Arr2'}

 $Same = (Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $Arr3 -DifferenceObject $Arr1).count -eq 0
if ($Same) { Write-Host '$Arr1 is equal to $Arr3' -ForegroundColor Cyan }
```